# asp button and modal

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So i have this button:

`<asp:Button ID="Buttonid" runat="server" Text="View"  BorderStyle="None" OnClick="Button_click_event" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></asp:Button>`

but then clicking the button will not toggle the OnClick Event, it will just show the modal.

But if i remove the `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"`. The onclick event will work, but obviously the modal will not popup anymore.

Help please. Thanks

Comment: Check the accepted answer, it might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390429/3518203

Answer (score 0):

The script that is controlling your model more than likely stops the regular functions of the button so will stop it posting back which will stop the event handler from being fired.

To get both client side and server side to fire you'll have to post back and then display the model when the page reloads.